# Slim PHP Framework Controller Directory

Tags: php, api, slim

I'm using Slim Framework for a new app and I want a controller directory in my src folder.   I keep getting the error message:

```
Callable \App\Controllers\MobileApiController does not exist
```

dependencies.php

```
$container['MobileApiController'] = function ($c)
{
    return new \App\Controllers\MobileApiController;
};
```

routes.php

```
$app->get('/user', '\App\Controllers\MobileApiController:getUser');
```

MobileApiController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

class MobileApiController
{

    protected $container;
    public function __construct($c) {
        $this->container = $c;
    }

    public function getUser($request, $response, $args)
    {
       var_dump($request);
    }
}
```

composer.json

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
```

The 'src' folder has a 'Controllers' folder and 'routes.php' and 'dependencies.php' files

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload`? I couldn't reproduce the error. It works for me.

Comment: Just move the App namespace`"App\\": "src/",` from `"autoload-dev"` to `"autoload"` in composer.json and run `composer update`.

Comment: @DanielO any reason to use `autoload` instead of  `autoload-dev`? Because the OP may really want to have some dev related classes that do not need to be included in a production environment.

Comment: @Nima Usually the namespace `Tests` (or Test) is dev-related only and `App` is prod and dev-related. The `Tests` namespace belongs to `autoload-dev` and `App` belongs to `autoload`.

Comment: Yes, but using `autoload-dev` should not cause any problems in this case, unless OP is passing `--no-dev` to composer. The point is I used `autoload-dev` to check the conditions described in the question and I couldn't reproduce the problem, so the problem should be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the namespace `Test` (singular) or `App\Test` is dev-related only and `App` is prod and dev-related. The `App\Test` namespace belongs to `autoload-dev` and `App` belongs to `autoload`.

Example (composer.json):

```
 "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "src/"
    },
  },
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\Test\\": "tests/"
    }
  },
```